# Maintaining RelativeLayout regardless of orientation

Tags: android, xml, layout, orientation

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The vertical view is exactly what I want, but the horizontal view becomes distorted. How can I force the ImageView to respect the align below the first TextView?

[Vertical view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6dwf.png)

[Horizontal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbiuv.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.firstcard.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="It's been a..."
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dachshund"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/dachshund"
    android:layout_below="@id/firstLine"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/dachshund"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:text="longgggggggggggg week"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit: Re-reading the Android documentation I discovered by alignBottom is the incorrect attribute.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix your need keep posting if further error ! or use linear layour for best result if not succeded

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:text="It's been a..."
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dachshund"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstLine"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_word" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dachshund"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:text="longgggggggggggg week"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your main issue here is that your parent layout's height and width are both set to "match_parent". This means that your entire view is confined to the size of the device's screen and thus everything is squeezed in. Try setting the height to "wrap_content" and the alignments should then be respected.

Comment: I tried, and it didn't work. I did notice an error in my code though. I had the ImageView aligned to ParentTop. Now that it's aligned to the first TextView, it lays better. Except that now the second TextView falls off the screen